# Jquery Mobile html pages not loading properly

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I used Jquery Mobile Framework for Phonegap project and I have used html pages for each page.

When I click to page css not loading properly until I reload the page.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Your question needs some more explanation.

Comment: How you are creating html page statically or dynamically. Provide some example in jsfiddle.

Comment: yes, i am creating pages statically, in root i have all html pages, in each page i am calling css under head section, the problem is when i click anchor link to other html pages, content not displays properly.

Answer (score 0):

Short explanation,

Have you put the link to the css file at every html file?

In case you don't, you can try adding data-ajax="false" in every anchor tag or adding the links to your css files at every html file.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for reply, it works fine but the problem is when i use data-ajax="false" page transition not working e.g:  data-transition="slide" not working page redirects like web page.

Comment: You can't set data-ajax="false" and have transitions, so I think that the best solution for you could be deleting data-ajax="false" and adding the link to your css files at every html page.

Comment: yes, i have included css file in all html pages head section. but no improvement.

Comment: So now, you have removed data-ajax="false". When you link to other html file with data-ajax="true" (it's default) the data-role="page" container is replaced. So the statics (css, js) on that page are not loaded. Then try loading everything in your first html file (main or index file).

Comment: yes, Now it's working fine. I added data-ajax="false" for index page alone link. Thanks for helping me to sortout this issue.